# How do you ask for user input in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, user-input

I'm trying to figure out how to ask for a user's input in list comprehension format.

```
SR = [srt for i in range (N) input("Enter a type of food")]
print (SR)
```

Assuming N was 2 for example, I would like to get a list that contains 2 user inputs essentially. However the code about doesn't work.

Comment: where are you getting `srt` from?

Comment: Maybe you want `SR = [input("Enter a type of food") for _ in range (N)]` but I would never use a list comprehension for that task.

Comment: @smac89 Whoops, I didn't mean to include the `srt` part. Sorry!

Comment: @smac89 I misunderstood the request. I still wouldn't personally use it, but that's a style and readability choice, not a technical problem with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong. This is how you do it

```
SR = [input("Enter a type of food: ") for _ in range (N)]
```

Comment: Thanks! So in general whenever I want to use list comprehension with user inputs, I should always have the input line come first before the for loop?

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob596, no this is just the way list comprehension works. The final output you want inside the list comes first and then the iterable comes next and finally there could be a predicate. In this case, the user input is what you want to store inside the list, so it goes first